# Is $\sum (-1)^{n-1}\tan \Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \Big) $ conditionally convergent or divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

> Investigate whether
> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\tan \Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \Big) $$
> is absolute convergent, conditionally convergent or divergent.
>
> Hint: $\tan(x)>x, \:\text{for} \: x\in ]0, \frac{\pi}{2}[$

It's not clear to me how to solve this. I tried the ratio test.

Call $a_n = (-1)^{n-1}\tan\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\Big)$. Then
$$\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}= \Bigg| - \frac{\tan \Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\Big)}{\tan \Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\Big)} \Bigg |  \to 1 \: \text{for} \: n \to \infty$$

But the ratio test is inconclusive, since the limit of the ratio is $1$. I can't see what other tests can help me here. I am also not sure how the hint helps at all.

Can someone push me forward?

Comment: **Hint :** For the fact that it doesn't converges absolutely, use your hint. For the fact that it does converges, use [Alternating series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series)

Answer (score 1):

When $x\to0$, we know that $\tan x=x+O(x^3)$, which indicates that
$$
\sum_n(-1)^{n-1}\tan\left(1\over\sqrt n\right)=\sum_n{(-1)^{n-1}\over\sqrt n}+O\left(\sum_n{1\over n^{3/2}}\right),
$$
the first series converges because of alternating series test, and the second one in the O term converges due to p-series test.